# widget in the lockscreen

Tags: android, widget, lockscreenwidget

I want to add a widget in the lock screen. On HTC ONE (android 4.4.3) I've added it, but somehow it's not on the main screen, you have to scroll to the second screen to see it and on Huawei Ascent P6 (android 4.2.2) I'm not able to add the widget on my lock screen. Here is my widget info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget1"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1">
</appwidget-provider>
```

and here is how it looks on the HTC ONE:

main lock screen:[image]

and here is how it looks on the second lock screen:
[image]

How can I make so the widget is shown on the main lock screen?